# convert curl to HttpRequest

Tags: http, curl, httprequest

I have a problem with curl request. I need cURL request looking like this change to HttpRequest or if it is not possible please give me an option how to implement cURL library into my project.

This is what I did so far and it is working but it cannot be that way.
.

```
Process process = runtime.exec(cUrlLoc + " -H \"apiAccessKeyId:" + userNameApi +
                    "\" -H \"apiSecretAccessKey:" + passwordApi +
                    "\" -H \"Accept:application/json\" -H \"Content-Type:multipart/form-data\" --form \"file=" + filePathName +
                    "\" --form \"params={actionType:SomeActionType}\" -X POST " + RestURL + "v1/bulk -k");
            int resultCode = process.waitFor();
```